# Natively support UUID as primary key in laravel (9+) models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I modified the model to use UUID instead of an incrementing number as primary key. Here is the migration:

```
Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(DB::raw('(UUID())'));
            $table->foreignUuid('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
});
```

I also modified the model by change keyType to string instead of default - integer - type:

```
class Game extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable = [
        "title",
        "user_id",
    ];
}
```

yet when I insert a new record using the create method, the id for new record is returning a 0

```
$game = Game::create([
    'title' => $request->input('title'),
    'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
]);

dd($game);
```

[image]

Even though the keytype is set to "string" in the result, the id field is still returning 0 (integer).

However, if I check the record that was created in the database, the id does contain a UUID string:
[image]

Can anyone please point me to what I am doing wrong here. I am pretty new to Laravel. Maybe I made a silly mistake somewhere. Also please let me know if I need to attach more reference material here. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using laravel 9+, you can use follow the official supported way https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#uuid-and-ulid-keys

Comment: On you raw to the db predefinition, remove the extra () to just:
`$table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(DB::raw('UUID()'));`

Comment: In the old days, you had to set incrementing to false for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comments on the post by Arun A S.

adding `use HasUuids` in `Game` Model fixes the issue:

```
//..
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
// other directives..

class Game extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, HasApiTokens;
    use HasUuids;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable = [
        "title",
        "user_id",
    ];
}
```